# ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "director" LINE 2: JOIN directors d ON mo.director.id = d.director.id (BEGINNER LEVEL)

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT mo.movie_name,d.first_name,d.last_names FROM movies mo
JOIN directors d ON mo.director.id = d.director.id
WHERE mo.movie_id IN 
(SELECT movie_id FROM movie_revenues
WHERE international_takings > domestic_takings);
```

Following a tutorial on Udemy and keep getting this
Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "director"
LINE 2: JOIN directors d ON mo.director.id = d.director.id

I have used the exact same syntax and punctation as a video tutorial I get. I also got the same error message when referencing the director table in an earlier query, although I dont understand where the error lies?

Comment: `d.director.id` should probably be: `d.director_id` and `mo.director.id` should probably be `mo.directory_id`

Comment: You are 100% correct. Cant believe I didnt see that